# "docker pull microsoft/aspnet" ERROR "no matching manifest......"

Tags: asp.net, docker

I was trying to run the aspnet image on Docker on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit machine.

But while trying to pull the aspnet from docker gives me below weird error.
'no matching manifest'

Any clue how to solve this problem.

Docker version: 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom right corner of the Windows machine, search for small Docker icon, right click on it and select option "Switch to Windows Containers"
Restart machine and try again.